# 3D objects rendered using OpenGL ES (iPad) overlap (fuse together)

Tags: ios, 3d, opengl-es-2.0, 3dsmax

I am a newbie at iOS programming, hence apologize in advance if this is a naive question. I exported a few objects (separately) from 3DS Max (as .obj) and then used the algorithm provided by Mr. Heiko Behrens which is available [here](http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/).

What the algorithm does is convert .obj files into header files (containing vertex, normal and texture co-ordinate data). This information is then read by Xcode to render these objects onto an iPad.

Now I tried to export all the objects together as one big .obj file but then the header file created is in a format that Xcode fails to read. So I exported every object individually making them 30 separate header files (corresponding to 30 objects) which contain vertices, normals and texture co-ordinates of the respective objects. Now for testing purposes I rendered the first 2 objects. I managed to do so but the 2 objects  are displayed as merged into one (or overlapped). I've also added code to make rotation of the object possible which verified that the 2 objects are fused together.

My questions are:

When I export separate obj files from 3DS Max, are the relative positions of these objects preserved? If not, how do I display these objects side-by-side instead of a fused unit?

Will I have to translate every object separately to the required position? If so, kindly guide me how?

I'd really appreciate any help/comments regarding my issue and thank you in advance!!

Thanks,
H

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show them side-by-side then you can do this trick:
Create a very tiny box, then center it at 0,0,0 , then move your mesh object to the side where ever you want it, then attach this object to the small box object in 0,0,0.

Create a new box for each new object you want to show, and attach it the same way to their own box.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion Stig. I looked around a little more and came up with the idea of assigning a property named 'position' (which would be an array for x, y and z co-ordinates) to every object and place them relative to each other. That way things become flexible and I can move them if I need to.